# Modify array json format

Tags: php, json

I have two json arrays, one different from the other.
I need to turn this array:

```
{
    "medidas": [
        {
            "desc_medida": "OMBROS",
            "tamanho": "G",
            "valor": 63
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "OMBROS",
            "tamanho": "GG",
            "valor": 64
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "OMBROS",
            "tamanho": "M",
            "valor": 62
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "OMBROS",
            "tamanho": "P",
            "valor": 60
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "BUSTO",
            "tamanho": "G",
            "valor": 110
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "BUSTO",
            "tamanho": "GG",
            "valor": 114
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "BUSTO",
            "tamanho": "M",
            "valor": 104
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "BUSTO",
            "tamanho": "P",
            "valor": 100
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "CINTURA",
            "tamanho": "G",
            "valor": 110
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "CINTURA",
            "tamanho": "GG",
            "valor": 114
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "CINTURA",
            "tamanho": "M",
            "valor": 104
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "CINTURA",
            "tamanho": "P",
            "valor": 100
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "COMPRIMENTO",
            "tamanho": "G",
            "valor": 97
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "COMPRIMENTO",
            "tamanho": "GG",
            "valor": 98
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "COMPRIMENTO",
            "tamanho": "M",
            "valor": 96
        },
        {
            "desc_medida": "COMPRIMENTO",
            "tamanho": "P",
            "valor": 95
        }
    ]
}
```

In this format:

```
{
    "header": ["TAMANHO", "OMBROS", "BUSTO", "CINTURA", "COMPRIMENTO"],
    "rows": {
        "P":  ["P", "60 cm", "100 cm", "100 cm", "95 cm"],
        "M":  ["M", "62 cm", "104 cm", "104 cm", "96 cm"],
        "G":  ["G", "63 cm", "110 cm", "110 cm", "97 cm"],
        "GG": ["GG", "64 cm", "114 cm", "114 cm", "98 cm"]
    }
}
```

I need to do this with PHP. I made many tests but could not get the result.

Here is my attempt:

```
$j = json_decode($json,true);

$count = count($j['medidas']);
$descArray = array();
$rowArray = array();
$header = '{ "header":[';
$rows = '"rows":{';

/* MONTA O HEADER */
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++){
    $descArray[$i] = $j['medidas'][$i]['desc_medida'];
}
$descArray = array_values(array_unique($descArray));
array_unshift($descArray, "TAMANHO");

$count = count($descArray);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $header .= '"'.$descArray[$i].'",';
}
$header = substr($header,0,-1) . '],';

/* MONTA A ROW */
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++){
    for($a = 0; $a < count($j['medidas'][$i]); $a++){
        $rows .= '"'.$j['medidas'][$i]['tamanho'].'"';
    }
}

echo $header.$rows;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($j);
echo "</pre>";
```

It gives me this output, which is not good:

```
{ "header":["TAMANHO","OMBROS","BUSTO","CINTURA","COMPRIMENTO"],
  "rows":{"G""G""G""GG""GG""GG""M""M""M""P""P""P""G""G""G"
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: You say you've tried many things that haven't worked... show us what you've attempted.

Comment: I stop here: http://pastebin.com/8j6h6S7S
I can not go forward

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need stdClass

```
$example_object = new stdClass();
$example_object->name = "Name";
$example_object->jobtitle = "Developer";
$example_object->arr = ['arrval1', 'arrval2'];

$json_data = json_encode($example_object);
print_r($json_data);
```

prints
`{"name":"Joe Bloggs","jobtitle":"Developer","arr":["arrval1","arrval2"]}`

UPD:

```
$descs = [];
$sizes = [];

foreach($json->medidas as $medida)
{
    $header = $medida->desc_medida;
    $size = $medida->tamanho;
    $size_value = $medida->valor;

    $descs[$header] = 1;
    $sizes[$size]['sizes'][] = $size_value . " cm";
}

$object = new stdClass;
$object->header = array_keys($descs);
$object->rows = new stdClass;

foreach (array_keys($sizes) as $size) {
    $object->rows->$size = array_merge([$size], $sizes[$size]['sizes']);
}


echo json_encode($object);
```

Comment: but we need to create an algorithm to modify this json

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is that you try to create JSON format yourself, which can be done so much easier if you first create the real object (or array) structure and then call `json_encode` on it.

Here is code that could do the job:

```
function transformJSON($inputJSON) {
    $input = json_decode($inputJSON);
    $output =  array(
        "header" => array("TAMANHO"),
        "rows" =>  array()
    );

    foreach ($input->medidas as $obj) {
        if (!in_array($obj->desc_medida, $output["header"])) {
            // add name to header
            $output["header"][] = $obj->desc_medida;
        }
        // add value to the right row
        $output["rows"][$obj->tamanho][] = $obj->valor . " cm";
    }
    // insert "GG" as first value in "GG" row, etc...
    foreach ($output["rows"] as $entry => $values) {
        array_unshift($output["rows"][$entry], $entry);
    }
    return json_encode($output);
}
```

Used with this example data:

```
$inputJSON = '{
"medidas": [
{
        "desc_medida": "OMBROS",
        "tamanho": "G",
        "valor": 63
},
{
        "desc_medida": "OMBROS",
        "tamanho": "GG",
        "valor": 64
},
{
        "desc_medida": "OMBROS",
        "tamanho": "M",
        "valor": 62
},
{
        "desc_medida": "OMBROS",
        "tamanho": "P",
        "valor": 60
},
{
        "desc_medida": "BUSTO",
        "tamanho": "G",
        "valor": 110
},
{
        "desc_medida": "BUSTO",
        "tamanho": "GG",
        "valor": 114
},
{
        "desc_medida": "BUSTO",
        "tamanho": "M",
        "valor": 104
},
{
        "desc_medida": "BUSTO",
        "tamanho": "P",
        "valor": 100
},
{
        "desc_medida": "CINTURA",
        "tamanho": "G",
        "valor": 110
},
{
        "desc_medida": "CINTURA",
        "tamanho": "GG",
        "valor": 114
},
{
        "desc_medida": "CINTURA",
        "tamanho": "M",
        "valor": 104
},
{
        "desc_medida": "CINTURA",
        "tamanho": "P",
        "valor": 100
},
{
        "desc_medida": "COMPRIMENTO",
        "tamanho": "G",
        "valor": 97
},
{
        "desc_medida": "COMPRIMENTO",
        "tamanho": "GG",
        "valor": 98
},
{
        "desc_medida": "COMPRIMENTO",
        "tamanho": "M",
        "valor": 96
},
{
        "desc_medida": "COMPRIMENTO",
        "tamanho": "P",
        "valor": 95
}
]
}';
```

You would call it like this:

```
$outputJSON = transformJSON($inputJSON);
echo $outputJSON;
```

Output is as you describe:

```
{
"header":["TAMANHO","OMBROS","BUSTO","CINTURA","COMPRIMENTO"],
"rows":{
"P":["P","60 cm","100 cm","100 cm","95 cm"],
"M":["M","62 cm","104 cm","104 cm","96 cm"],
"G":["G","63 cm","110 cm","110 cm","97 cm"],
"GG":["GG","64 cm","114 cm","114 cm","98 cm"]
}
}
```